# Does memtest86+ test memory which is used to run itself?

Tags: linux, memory, boot

One of the common server failure scenarios is bad DRAM, sometimes even when ECC memory is used.

`memtest86+` is one of the most useful tools to diagnose DRAM problems. As it loads itself at the start of the memory, I've been wondering if `memtest86+` checks the part of the memory which `memtest86+`is loaded into.

Is the memory allocated to `memtest86+`so small that it doesn't matter, or is it possible that `memtest86+` could miss a defect in the DRAM because it can't test the memory locations it's residing in?

Comment: While this question is relevant for a server, it's also relevant for an ordinary PC, so I've voted to move this question to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) where it can reach more people.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Obviously, memtest86+ cannot test the memory region which currently contains the memtest86+ executable code (but if there are memory errors in that region, it is very likely that the test itself will crash). However, memtest86+ is able to relocate its own code to a different address at runtime, and by using this trick it is able to test all memory which it is allowed to use by the firmware (BIOS) — just not all at once.

This code relocation is described in README.background inside the memtest86+ source code archive (the file is slightly out of date — e.g., it states that the addresses used for memtest86+ code are 0x2000 and 0x200000, but the low address as defined in the source is actually 0x10000, and the high address is either 0x2000000 or 0x300000 depending on the amount of memory in the machine).

But even with this relocation trick memtest86+ is not able to test all memory for the following reasons:

- Usually the firmware (BIOS) reserves some RAM regions for its own use (e.g., ACPI tables). While these RAM regions can be accessed by CPU, writing anything into them can result in unpredictable behavior.
- Some part of RAM is used for the [System Management  Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) and is not even accessible from the CPU outside of the privileged SMM code.
- The RAM address range between 640K and 1M is inaccessible due to quirks of the legacy PC memory layout (some of this RAM may be used as a shadow for BIOS ROM and for SMM, other parts may be completely inaccessible).

Comment: Interesting, I missed its relocation capability. Obviously SMM and the likes are out of range (apart specific BIOS support).

Comment: Those mapped regions generally exclude the DRAM as something else "off module" is being addressed ? ROM and peripheral devices say.

Comment: if you have several ram modules, perform a second test after having swapped them...

Comment: Is it possible to have memory fail in just the right way to have memtest incorrectly report success due to having its instructions rewritten? Or rather, how many faults does it take?

Comment: @JanDvorak: In theory, it's possible, of course. In practice, I'd say it's only slightly more likely than banging your head on the keyboard and randomly typing out a Shakespearean sonnet.

Answer (score 5):

No, memtest can't test its own memory. However, it is so small (only some KB) that it hardly matters. **EDIT:** this statement is wrong since, as stated in the selected answer, memtest can dynamically relocate itself to test *all* user addressable memory.

--

In theory, modern processor can, at boot time, configure part of their cache as programmable memory, from within very small programs (as memtest) can be run **without** touching DRAM at all.

However, it is a model-specific feature (which require BIOS support) and I don't think memtest is using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `memtest` is testing the CPU cache as well. So if `memtest` would be loaded into this cache, then it this part of the cache couldn't be tested, which is more problematic, because it's much smaller than the memory?

Comment: Besed on [memtest86 documentation](http://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm) it does **not** test the processor cache, at least in a direct manner. Moreover, modern processors have separate instructions and data cache (I$ and D$). Executable code is loaded into the instruction cache and it can't be directly modified / overwritten

Comment: memtest86+ definitely tests the CPUs data cache, but that doesn't matter for this question. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I thought it copied itself somewhere else while testing the memory it normally lives in.  That's why every test has a slow part (most of memory) and a really fast part (the tiny bit where its code/data is stored).

Comment: @Robin any reference on "memtest86+ definitely tests the CPUs data cache"? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86) doesn't seem to agree: "access patterns are designed to keep most cache organizations flushed so that memory accesses are actually seen to the RAM"

Comment: As mentioned in Sergey's answer, memtest86+ relocates itself, so it effectively does test its own memory.  I think this answer is misleading.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: memtest86+ tests L1, L2 and L3 caches of a CPU, which is the data cache, right?

Comment: @NateEldredge true. I edited it to point to the correct answer.

Comment: @Robin by reference I mean a link to some kind of source which confirms what you say. So far, I've only seen Wikipedia which says it doesn't

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/16/0122/h_1453462950_5192344_b15635706a.png

Comment: @Robin I bet info on that screenshot comes from [`cpuid`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86). Testing the cache would mean you write a pattern in each cache line and read it back.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Ah okay.. so I've learnt something more :-) Cool thanks!

Comment: @shodanshok, for what it's worth, [__memtest86__](http://www.memtest86.com/) and [__memtest86+__](http://www.memtest.org/) are different programs.